# window.location.href ="#find" works on mobile but not on PC. Ok on local site (Expressions 4)

Tags: javascript

Function findme works fine on mobiles and in development using Expressions 4 (local host) however when installed on a remote host on a IE browser the function findme gets called but the page find is not displayed.

window.location.href ="#find"; works on local host and on mobile on remote host but not on a PC when running from a remote host.

Any recommendations?

```
<head> 
<title>Page Title</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-  width, initial-scale=1">       
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" /> 
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script> 
<script> 
function findme(){ 
    alert('find'); 
    window.location.href ="#find"; 
} 
</script>
```

```
<body>
<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-body-b">
<div data-role="navbar" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#help"  >HELP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="findme();" data-transition="slide"  >FIND</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">
<h3>page 1</h3>
</div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
<div  data-role="page" id="help" >
<div id="map1" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-body-b">
    <h3>i-Duress</h3>
<div data-role="navbar" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" data-transition="slide">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#map" o >Map</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">
<h3>Help PAGE</h3>
</div><!-- /content -->

</div>
<div  data-role="page" id="find" >
<div id="find" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-body-b">
<div data-role="navbar" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" data-transition="slide">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">
<h3>FIND PAGE</h3>
</div><!-- /content -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.location.href="http://www.google.com"; try using this

Comment: Ok IE is a different story :) Did you tested on Chrome, Firefox, Safari? And if so, did you encounter the problem there?

Comment: window.event.returnValue = false; have this before the code, might work

Comment: Can you share a fiddle?

Comment: Is there a reason why you change the hash using js in that case? Why don't you write `<a href="#find" onclick="findme();" data-transition="slide"  >FIND</a>` and remove the `window.location.href ="#find"` from your `findme()` function?

Comment: Thanks - I need to get some data from a database (JS script) before navigating to the #find page

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change your `href` attribute value for `FIND` link. Put `javascript:void(0)` instead of `#`.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="findme();" data-transition="slide"  >FIND</a>
```

Comment: Thanks - Arin I give it a try.